# Can Rails 2 different databases in the production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

My goal is to have 2 databases and 2 deployments of rails on the same server. I want to have the regular production server using the production database. Then I want to be able to deploy to a different web address that will use a different database. My goal is to be able to push the backup first and make sure all the migrations etc. work in the full environment. I would then push it to the main server.

The issue I seem to run into is that the database.ml file only lists the 3 database types. The passenger environment will also assume that its running in production and would migrate the main MySQL database even if I deploy the code to a different directory. Whats the best way around this? Was wondering if it is simple or if it involves setting lots of variables in lots of places? Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add other database types to database.yml as you see fit.

```
staging:
  adapter: postgresql 
  host: mydb_host
  database: mydb_staging
  etc...
```

You can copy config/environments/production.rb to config/environments/staging.rb and leave it as is so the two environments are exactly the same, or tweak staging.rb as you see fit.

Now you have a staging environment!  Use it where appropriate, e.g.:

```
rake RAILS_ENV=staging db:migrate
```

I am not a passenger expert, but know that my shop has both staging and production instances of apps running on the same server under passenger, so it can be done.  Google can probably instruct you better on configuring that than I can.

Comment: Looks like it might be as easy as putting this in the virtual cots config: rails_env staging